# Heat and work are path dependent functions. Give some examples

Tags: thermodynamics

I dont understand how can the amount of work done be different when the inital and final states are the same if it has followed a different path . in the same way heat also baffles me because heat is a form of energy still is not a state function whereas other forms of energy are

Comment: do you mean "when the initial and final states are the same?"

Comment: Heat is *not* a form of energy. Heat is a quantity that measures the amount of energy (in some form) transferred from one object to another object. It is a *descriptor* of a process, *not* an actual "thing". The same is true of work.

Comment: Yes i meant when initial and final states are same . sorry for the typo error . So u basically want to say that heat is a parameter . then if i say heat is the amount of "energy" transferred i am just talking about the quantity not the energy . somewhat like a mole isnt it . plzz correct me if i m wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have an ideal gas, which satisfies $PV= NKT$. Also, according to the first law of thermodynamics, work done by external forces will be $dW=-P dV$. This means that if the gas expands, the "external forces" do negative work, that means they are actually gaining energy. Now, imagine we do this cycle:

[image]

A) At constant preassure $P_A$, rise the volume from $V_D$ to $V_B$. This will give $W_{A}=-P_A (V_B-V_D)$.

B) At constant volume $V_B$, lower the preassure from $P_A$ to $P_C$. This will not do work because $dW=-P dV$ so if we don't have volume variation we don't get work.

C) Now, at constant preassure $P_C$, lower back volume from $V_B$ to $V_D$ to get to the point where we started. This will do $W_{C}=-P_C(V_D-V_B)$

D) Rise preassure from $P_C$ to $P_A$ at constant volume $V_D$. Again, this will not do work.

Now, the work done in $A$ would be the opposite of the work done in $C$ but, because the volume variation was done at different preassures, $W_{A}$ is higher than $W_{C}$.

This example shows that, although we made a cycle and came back to a point with the same preasure and volume (and thus same temperature) the work done in the cycle wasn't zero. This is, as you said, because Work is not a state function.

Work and Heat are not state functions *in a way that makes energy a state function*. They compensate their bad behaviour.

There's an easy example to see this. Suppose you want to heat water from temperatures $T_1$ to $T_2$. If you do it *adiabatically* doing mechanic work then $\Delta U = \Delta W$ so work will be a state function as $U$. If you do it by heating the water *without doing mechanical work* then $\Delta U = \Delta Q$ so now heat will be a state function as $U$. But if you do it in a weird way combining heating and doing mechanical work, the work done and the heat transfered in the process would differ from those in the previous examples. However, energy $U$ must be still a state function, so $dW$ and $dQ$ must compensate somehow to give the first law of thermodynamics:

$dU = dQ + dW$

Comment: Thnx for helping me to understand . i think the concept is much more clearer now.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! I'm glad you found the answer useful. If you beleive it's the right answer, click the button on the left to say so. That way this question is tagged as answered. If you still want to hear some different answer don't do it, jaja.